# chrome installed apps address bar hide

Tags: google-chrome

[look its new address bar remove these white panels
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfIuv.jpg)very amazing things are happening in chrome,

Initially, prominent sites like Discord lacked the "Install App" button. After a month, I found a workaround: force installation via a windowed shortcut.

Now, every interaction prompts an intrusive pop-up. Can the address bar and this pop-up be removed for a smoother user experience? Your insights are appreciated.

(stacksdemand220character) Resolved Discord install snag by crafting a windowed shortcut. Seeking advice to remove intrusive pop-ups for enhanced user delight.